# Multiple headers, footers and details with FileHelpers

Tags: filehelpers

I would like to write / read a text file using the FileHelpers library.

However I have doubts on how to proceed when the file has several headers, footers and details.

The structure of my file is as follows:

```
FileHeader
  AHeader
    ADetail
    ADetail
    ADetail
  AFooter
  BHeader
    BDetail
    BDetail
  BFooter
  CHeader
    CDetail
    CDetail
    CDetail
    CDetail
  CFooter
FileFooter
```

Does anyone know indicate a possible way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultiRecording engine to read or write a file with many different layouts. 
http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/

Comment: Using MultiRecordEngine how would I do to write different lists of objects in a single file in a certain order?
And to make the reading I can separate each block of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, using FileHelpers for a format that complex would be difficult.

FileHelpers provides two methods of handling multiple record types: [the master/detail engine](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/MasterDetail/MasterDetailCustomSelector/) and the [multi-record engine](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/).

Unfortunately it is likely that you need both for your format. It would be hard to combine them without some further coding.

To be clear

- the [`MasterDetailEngine`](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/MasterDetail/MasterDetailCustomSelector/) caters for header/footer situation, but it currently supports only one detail type and only one level of nesting.
- the [`MultiRecordEngine`](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/) allows multiple record types. However, it treats each row as an unrelated record and the hierarchy (that is, which detail record belongs to which master record) would be hard to determine.

Comment: Exactly the problem. I could do the writing. I created a helper class where I spend a generic registry and the file. Using FileHelperEngine with AppendToFile I can write various types of objects in the same file.
It now remains to create a way to read the files.